# Applescript calling python file with modules included

Tags: python, applescript

I am running an apple script that will run a python file upon the mac waking up from sleep. The applescript works and runs the python file. The problem is that if I try and run a python file that would uses modules then the file wont run. The error i get is saying that the computer cannot find the specific module.
in development i use a pipenv to install the modules.
If i could some how run a `pipenv install required-modules` either from the apple script or the python file i think this would solve my problem.
There is a thread on here that mentions trying to run AppleScript => bash => python file. However I have looked into it but my lack of knowledge is not enough to figure it out.

So my question is can a '`pipenv install required-modules'` be run from an apple script or a python file?

I am running the python file from the following apple script:

```
set desktop_folder to "$HOME/Desktop"
do shell script "python " & desktop_folder & "/foobar/main.py"
```

Comment: I suspect this is a search-path issue. `do shell script` uses a default (stripped down) PATH variable. One of the search paths for modules in Python is sys.path, which (I think) refers to the shell PATH variable. You may need to set the path to the module explicitly in your script, though I'm not enough of a python person to tell you how to do that.  see [Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)

Comment: Amazing, i just had to go into my PyCharm and copy over the path to where the virtual environments live. perfect thanks